# REACT React how to access the correct "this" after a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently started learning React and after attaching a callback to a child element I lost the reference of "this" in the parent element. I am building a simple task and when it is checked. I send it back to the parent so that the parent can delete it and reassign the state to the new array without the element. However, I dont have access to this.state.todosTask. I get undefined.
Below is my code.

```
Parent Element TodoList

 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      todosTask: props.todos
    }
  }
  handleCheckedTask(task){
    console.log("Now Im in the todost"+task)
   this.state.todosTask //= Undefined
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h4>Todo List</h4>
        <div className="form-check">
        <label className="form-check-label">
          {this.state.todosTask.map((todoElement)=>{
                return <Todo todo={todoElement} key={todoElement.id} onCheckedTask={this.handleCheckedTask}/>
          })}
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Child Component

```
  completed(event){
    let self = this
    let task = self.props.todo.task
    let id = self.props.todo.id
    console.log(self.refs.complete)
    this.props.onCheckedTask({id:id,task:task})
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input
        className="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        ref="complete"
        onChange={this.completed.bind(this)}/>
        {this.props.todo.task}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `handleCheckedTask` in the constructor to this.

Explanation: In javascript functions and methods are not bound to the containing object as in other languages, like in Java. In javascript `this` is dynamic, and it (mostly) means "the caller of the function". For most of the cases, it doesn't make a difference, as normally we call the method through the containing object, as in `console.log("foo")`. But sometimes, we want to pass the function as a callback, in this case, the caller is not the object where it was defined, <del>but the one that is using the callback.</del>  Fortunately we have 2 ways to fix this problem:

1. Binding the method to an object, with `.bind()`
2. Not passing `this` to the function and get it from the lexical context. (i.e. Using an arrow function).

.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todosTask: props.todos
    };
    this.handleCheckedTask = this.handleCheckedTask.bind(this);
}
```

Alternatively you can define your handler using a property initializer.

```
  handleCheckedTask = (task) => {
    console.log("Now Im in the todost"+task)
    this.state.todosTask //= Undefined
  }
```

You can check the details [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding)

**Edit:** I removed the part where I said that the caller of the callback was the object that was calling it. Normally for callbacks, `this` is undefined for normal functions (not arrow functions). For arrow functions `this` is recovered from the closure, that is, from the lexical context where it was defined.

Comment: Perfect. Binding it to the constructor gave me control of this for the entire class. I am alittle confused as to why I have to manually bind it. Can you please explain what is happening in the constructor when I manually bind it there.

Comment: I added an explanation to my response.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 does not have automatic this binding. So, this should be bound manually in the constructor.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todosTask: props.todos
    };
    this.handleCheckedTask = this.handleCheckedTask.bind(this);
}
```